# Unable to configure Spring Cloud Consul for specific profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

I'm trying to configure spring cloud consul for a specific profile but when I try to run the application I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Config data location 'consul:' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'consul:' at class path resource [application-local.properties] - 6:22 is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I update `spring.config.import` to `spring.config.import=optional:consul:` in `application-local.properties`, consul configuration is ignored and the configuration from the properties file is used instead of consul.

`application.properties`:

```
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false
```

`application-local.properties`:

```
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=true
spring.config.import=consul:

spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.config.watch.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.config.watch.delay=6000
spring.cloud.consul.config.watch.wait-time=1
spring.cloud.consul.config.profile-separator=_
```

It seems that Spring is not overriding the default configuration with the one specified in `application-local.properties`.  I also tried configuring consul in `bootstrap.properties` and `bootstrap-local.properties` but I got the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

No spring.config.import property has been defined

Action:

Add a spring.config.import=consul: property to your configuration.
    If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:consul: instead.
    To disable this check, set spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false or 
    spring.cloud.consul.config.import-check.enabled=false.
```

I'm using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config:3.0.3` and spring boot 2.4.7

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the following in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this before, so first you can add below dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and second, create a bootstrap.yml file. you can set your profile here and have separate configuration like below:

```
        spring:
      profiles:
        active: dev
        include:
          - consul
    #      - offline
      cloud:
        consul:
          host: 10.20.8.67
          port: 8500
          config:
            enabled: false
          discovery:
            heartbeat:
              enabled: true
              ttl: 5s
            acl-token: 4319cf67-2690-62b3-a8bb-623d79b92737
          service-registry:
            enabled: true
          retry:
            enabled: true
            max-attempts: 1
      application:
        name: servicename
    server:
      port: 8090
    
    ---
    
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: offline
  cloud:
    bus:
      enabled: false
    consul:
      config:
        enabled: false
  application:
    name: servicename
```

in this case, if you set include profile to offline, the offline section property will use and disable your config consul. with bootstrap.yml you can enable or disable discovery or config feature in consul. you can also use active profile directly instead of include profile group.

Comment: I read on documentation "With Spring Cloud Vault 3.0 and Spring Boot 2.4, the bootstrap context initialization (bootstrap.yml, bootstrap.properties) of property sources was deprecated.", so i thought should do away with boostrap files.